# Hokuyo laser data to composite 3D map

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, laser-assembler, laser-pipeline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've just finished all of the laser pipeline tutorials using the laser.bag data provided by ROS. Now I want to use my Hokuyo laser to read in data and then turn that data into a 3D composite map. When I record data both the Fixed Frame and Target Frame are "/laser". What do I need to change in the source code or launch file to get this data to read in correctly to Rviz. I will provide the source code and launch file below.

**Launch File**

`<launch>`

`<node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="assembler_test" name="my_assembler">`

`<remap from="scan" to="tilt_scan"/>`

`<param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />`

`<param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />`

`</node>`

`</launch>`

**Laser_scan_assembler.cpp**

```
#include "laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "laser_assembler/base_assembler.h"
#include "filters/filter_chain.h"

using namespace laser_geometry;
using namespace std ;

namespace laser_assembler
{


class LaserScanAssembler : public BaseAssembler<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>
{  
public:
  LaserScanAssembler() : BaseAssembler<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("max_scans"), filter_chain_("sensor_msgs::LaserScan")
  {
    // ***** Set Laser Projection Method *****
    private_ns_.param("ignore_laser_skew", ignore_laser_skew_, true);

    // configure the filter chain from the parameter server
    filter_chain_.configure("filters", private_ns_);

    // Have different callbacks, depending on whether or not we want to ignore laser skews.
    if (ignore_laser_skew_)
      start("scan");
    else
    {
      start();
      skew_scan_sub_ = n_.subscribe("scan", 10, &LaserScanAssembler::scanCallback, this);
    }
  }

  ~LaserScanAssembler()
  {

  }

  unsigned int GetPointsInScan(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan& scan)
  {
    return (scan.ranges.size ());
  }

  void ConvertToCloud(const string& fixed_frame_id, const  sensor_msgs::LaserScan& scan_in, sensor_msgs::PointCloud& cloud_out)
  {
    // apply filters on laser scan
    filter_chain_.update (scan_in, scan_filtered_);

    // convert laser scan to point cloud
    if (ignore_laser_skew_)  // Do it the fast (approximate) way
    {
      projector_.projectLaser(scan_filtered_, cloud_out);
      if (cloud_out.header.frame_id != fixed_frame_id)
        tf_->transformPointCloud(fixed_frame_id, cloud_out, cloud_out);
    }
    else                     // Do it the slower (more accurate) way
    {
      int mask = laser_geometry::channel_option::Intensity +
                 laser_geometry::channel_option::Distance +
                 laser_geometry::channel_option::Index +
                 laser_geometry::channel_option::Timestamp;
      projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud (fixed_frame_id, scan_filtered_, cloud_out, *tf_, mask);
    }
    return;
  }

  void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr& laser_scan)
  {
    if (!ignore_laser_skew_)
    {
      ros::Duration cur_tolerance = ros::Duration(laser_scan->time_increment * laser_scan->ranges.size());
      if (cur_tolerance > max_tolerance_)
      {
        ROS_DEBUG("Upping tf tolerance from [%.4fs] to [%.4fs]", max_tolerance_.toSec(), cur_tolerance.toSec());
        assert(tf_filter_);
        tf_filter_->setTolerance(cur_tolerance);
        max_tolerance_ = cur_tolerance;
      }
      tf_filter_->add(laser_scan);
    }
  }

private:
  bool ignore_laser_skew_;
  laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;

  ros::Subscriber skew_scan_sub_;
  ros::Duration max_tolerance_;   // The longest tolerance we've needed on a scan so far

  filters::FilterChain<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> filter_chain_;
  mutable sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan_filtered_;

};

}

using namespace laser_assembler ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "laser_scan_assembler");
  LaserScanAssembler pc_assembler;
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11553/hokuyo-laser-data-to-composite-3d-map/) by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to change the launch file from the `tilt_scan` value in the line `<remap from="scan" to="tilt_scan"/>` to the topic that the hokuyo publishes (base_scan/scan?). Also, in the launch file, it specifies the "fixed_frame". What this means is that the data coming from the scanner will be transformed into the robot's base_link frame. If you change this frame to "/laser", all of the assembled data will be displayed with respect to the laser, rather than with respect to the main body of the robot. You might want this to happen. If so, change the value of "fixed_frame" to "/laser". Otherwise, you can leave it as "base_link"

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1